# How should I tell ri to look in a path for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ri

I have the file named new-c.ri and I want to use ri to see its usage. However, it is not in the default directory where ri looks for. How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the -d option to add a directory to the search paths.